# intdiv() is not working as expected

Tags: php, math, decimal, division

I am using this function but result not coming as expected

```
function getyearly($monthly, $yearly)
    {
        if(!empty($monthly) && $monthly!='0' && !empty($yearly) && $yearly!='0')
        {
            $permonth = intdiv((int)$yearly, 12);
            $monthlytoyear = (int)$monthly*12;
            $aftersub = $monthlytoyear - (int)$yearly;
            $afterdiv = intdiv((int)$aftersub, (int)$yearly);
            // $finaly = (int)$afterdiv*100;
            return "$ " . $yearly . "/year ($" . round($permonth) . "/month; save ~" . (int)$afterdiv . "%)";
        } else {
            return '$ '.$yearly.'/yearly';
        }
    }
```

I am getting zero(`0`).

Comment: intdiv = check if that function is working as expected

Comment: 'works' for me https://ideone.com/CzUzlw sure about your inputs?

Comment: my inputs are 
$monthly='40', $yearly= '420'

Comment: $ 420/year ($35/month; save ~0%) as i said, works just fine https://ideone.com/CzUzlw

Comment: works fine but how can i get
60/480=0.125

Comment: dont have an idea kindly enplane me where i am doing problem

Comment: Why are you suddenly using 60 and 480?  `empty() ` filters out zero-ish (`"0"` and `0`) values by default -- you don't need conditional checks 2 and 4.

Comment: i have Placed these checks because some time there could me empty string or sometimes there can '0'.
why echo $afterdiv=intdiv(60,480);
returns 0
https://ideone.com/CVHWIJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intdiv()` is the wrong tool for that last job.

The result of the division will be a float which `intdiv` will convert to `0`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/U1nVo))

```
function getyearly($monthly, $yearly) {
    if(!empty($monthly) && !empty($yearly)) {
        $permonth=intdiv((int)$yearly, 12);
        echo "Single payment will feel like 12-monthly payments of: $permonth (" , $permonth *12 . ")\n";
        $monthlytoyear=(int)$monthly*12;
        echo "Making monthly payments will actually come to: $monthlytoyear\n";
        $aftersub = $monthlytoyear-$yearly;
        echo "That is a difference of: $aftersub\n";
        $afterdiv = $aftersub / $yearly;
        echo "In other words, a savings of: " , $afterdiv , "\n";
        $finaly=(int)($afterdiv*100);
        return "$ ".$yearly."/year ($".round($permonth)."/month; save ~{$finaly}%)";
    } else {
        return '$ '.$yearly.'/yearly';
    }

}
$monthly='60';
$yearly= '480'; 

echo getyearly($monthly,$yearly);
```

Output:

```
Single payment will feel like 12-monthly payments of: 40 (480)
Making monthly payments will actually come to: 720
That is a difference of: 240
In other words, a savings of: 0.5
$ 480/year ($40/month; save ~50%)
```